# How to use time in a smooth fitted with gam

Tags: r, model, smoothing

I'm fitting a model to predict occurrence of a natural hazard (say, rockfall) in space and time. My model includes some standard variables that are used in logistic regression, and a smooth that includes position (the X and Y coordinates) and time of occurrence (the T coordinate). In other words, I am looking for the numbers behind this sentence: "Given this location's slope steepness, solar insolation and vegetation, and its proximity in time and space to other occurrrences of rockfall, what is the current risk of rockfall?"
The model is fitted seemingly successfully and the performance (expressed in my case as the Area Under Curve) is satisfactory. However, the current model's prediction is affected by not only past but also future occurrences of rockfall. I would like to avoid that, but don't know how to.

I am hoping that gam, whose documentation I can barely comprehend, has an option to fit smooths in only one direction. It's okay to fit a smooth using other occurrences of rockfall with higher or lower X-coordinate, and other occurrences with lower T-coordinate, but not other occurrences with higher T-coordinate. 
Alternatively, I'd be happy to take the model that I have fitted already, but then use it to predict in a different way that deals with time differently than with space.
I found no way forward with either of these questions.

```
m_var_xyt <- bam(rockfall_occurrence ~ steepness + insolate + veg + s(X,Y,T, bs="tp",k=10),
               family=binomial(link = "probit"), 
               data=xytset,
               na.action=na.omit)
xytset$pred = c(predict(m_var_xyt,newdata=xytset,typ="response"))
```